# "Surjections have Right Inverse" to the "Axiom of Choice"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have learned that the statements
"Every surjective function has right inverse" and the "Axiom of Choice" are equivalent each other. I could easily prove the $\Longleftarrow$ direction, but it's little tricky to do the reverse direction. The problematic part is that we can reduce the AC, that is,
$$\text{For any set } I, \text{ if } \forall i\in I, A_i\text{ are nonempty sets then there exist a choice function } \\
f:I\longrightarrow \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \text{ such that } \forall i\in I, f(i)\in A_i$$
to a statement that
$$\text{For any set } I, \text{ if } \forall i\in I, A_i\text{ are nonempty pairwise disjoint sets then there exist a choice function }\\ f:I\longrightarrow \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \text{ such that } \forall i\in I, f(i)\in A_i.$$
So that we can construct a surjection and make the right inverse. By reducing, I found that one uses the argument like this; [surjection and axiom of choice.](https://planetmath.org/SurjectionAndAxiomOfChoice)

But my question is, what if for some $i, j\in I, i\neq j, A_i=A_j$? Then we can't use this argument, because they make new collection which is no more disjoint.

So finally, I want to know what's wrong with my counterexample. If my counterexample is appropriate, then please give a perfect proof or idea of reducing statement. Thanks for reading my long question.

Comment: I don't understand your first question. Assuming that every surjective function has a right inverse we can show that $\sf AC$ holds for pairwise disjoint sets, and since this version of $\sf AC$ is equivalent to the usual one, you can prove thus the existence of a choice function for the case of existing $i,j \in I$ with $i \neq j$ and $A_i \neq A_j$. Perhaps you're asking for a proof which doesn't involve the pairwise disjoint set version of $\sf AC$?

Comment: So I'm asking for a proof that why AC-disjoint is equivalent to AC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call your second statement AC-disjoint. Clearly AC implies AC-disjoint. Conversely assume that we are given a family of nonempty sets $A_i$. Define $A'_i = A_i \times \{i\} \subset (\bigcup A_i) \times I$. These sets are pairwise disjoimt. By AC-disjoint there exists a choice function $f' : I \to \bigcup A'_i$ such that $f'(i) \in A'_i$. Then
$$f = p \circ f' : I \to \bigcup A_i$$
with projection $p : (\bigcup A_i) \times I \to \bigcup A_i$ is the desired choice function.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did this type of proof before but I wasn't quite sure. I maybe confused some concepts like union and cartesian product, ordered pair somehow. After your proof it became very clear now.